# Trying to plot a histogram with randomly generated data in js with highcharts but my code does not work?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

There is a problem with getting the code to read the normally distributed data, but I have no idea how to fix this problem. I am trying to implement the histogram using highcharts.

```js
var data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  data.push(Math.random() * (0.5 - (-0.5)) + (-0.5));
};
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: 'Histogram'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Bins'
    },
    categories: [-0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.35, -0.3, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0,
      0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 0.5
    ],
    min: -0.5,
    max: 0.5,
    tickInterval: 0.05,
    gridLineWidth: 0
  },
  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Frequency'
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Data',
    data: data
    // normally distributed data here
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      groupPadding: 0
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Where should I try to move the data for the code to be working?

I am trying to plot a histogram.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you are trying to do with all these meaningless categories in your `xAxis` configuration and I think you may need a **linear** scale.

You should read [this part of the documentation about **axis types**](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/axes#axis-types).

Here is a basic example:

```js
let data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  data.push(Math.random() - 0.5);
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'Series',
    data
  }]
});
```

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/10.3.3/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In principle, a histogram is used to show, reflecting a series of points on a column chart where the columns are the bins in which the points are located. If you want to show your points on a category type axis it might look like this.

At this [documentation](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/histogram-series), it's explained how to create histogram series.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wLmu62a9/

```js
const data = [-0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.35, -0.3, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0,
  0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3
];

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Histogram'
  },

  xAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Bins'
    },
    categories: [-0.5, -0.45, -0.4, -0.35, -0.3, -0.25, -0.2, -0.15, -0.1, -0.05, 0,
      0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, 0.4, 0.45, 5.5
    ],
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Histogram'
    },
    alignTicks: false,
    opposite: true
  }],

  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: 'Data'
    }
  }, {
    title: {
      text: 'Histogram'
    },
    opposite: true
  }],

  series: [{
    name: 'Histogram',
    type: 'histogram',
    xAxis: 1,
    yAxis: 1,
    baseSeries: 's1',
    zIndex: -1
  }, {
    name: 'Data',
    type: 'scatter',
    data: data,
    id: 's1',
    marker: {
      radius: 1.5
    }
  }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/histogram-bellcurve.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>



<div id="container"></div>
```